# jQuery confirm / cancel home made function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, prompt

I've made my own, home-made, yes/no function but it won't work.

Here is the function:

```
function CoverAndShow (title, text, type) {
    if (type == "confirm") {
        $("body").append("<div class='msg'><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + text + "</p><input class='ok' type='button' value='OK' /><input type='button' class='cancel' value='Cancel' /></div>");
    }

    $(".ok").click(function() {
        return true;
    });

    $(".cancel").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
}
```

And here is my code for click "OK" in the function:

```
    $("#ask").click(function() {

    if (CoverAndShow("Title","Should I operate?", "confirm") == true) {
        alert("true");
    }
```

This won't work and won't return anything.
Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: which part is wont work?

Comment: It should be === true

Comment: == should be ok as long as you don't need a check for datatype, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Undefined_variable, nope, this isn't working either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to use a callback here. You can't return from this kind of function (look up asyncronity). You pass a function as the last parameter to `CoverAndShow`, and then it gets called with the return value.

```js
function CoverAndShow (title, text, type, callback) {
    if (type == "confirm") {
        $("body").append("<div class='msg'><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + text + "</p><input class='ok' type='button' value='OK' /><input type='button' class='cancel' value='Cancel' /></div>");
    }

    $(".ok").click(function() {
        callback(true);
    });

    $(".cancel").click(function() {
        callback(false);
    });
}

$("#ask").click(function() {

   CoverAndShow("Title","Should I operate?", "confirm", function(ret){
      if (ret) { // no need to explicitly check for true
         alert("true");
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ask">ask</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an "unexpected token return" error, could you fiddle this?

Comment: Fixed. I used the new Stack Snippet feature for you to run it right here in the answer. :)